# Generating and downloading a CSV - stream does not support seeking (not remote)

Tags: php

I am trying to have my code download the file in .csv format, I did manage this and it worked perfectly except it includes an additional field containing (#Resource ID XX), which I don't want. I did some browsing and read many answers saying that the below code should be used:

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 


foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
} 

rewind($fp);
$output = stream_get_contents($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

This is giving me the following error : `rewind(): stream does not support seeking in /var/www/opencart/admin/model/catalog/upload.php on line 30`, from what I understand this is usually because fopen is used on something external, mine isn't I don't believe..so i'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: So why are you doing the `rewind()` and the `$output = stream_get_contents($fp);`? Unless you plan on doing something with $outut, they're redundant

Comment: Incidentally, `php://output` is sending data to the output stream (effectively to the client's browser, assuming it's a web request), so should be considered external.... once you've started sending data to the browser, how can you call it back and change it?

Comment: I use output with headers to download the file later. Also I thought that php://output would have been external as well but another post suggested it as a fix for the very  problem im having

Comment: Consider `php://output` as the equivalent of echo: unless you're using output buffering as well, then it is sending to the browser (for web requests). If you need to add headers, add them __before__ sending the data to `php://output`, or use a temporary file, or output buffering

Comment: and I think it caches it, i dont think it is a web request

Comment: The headers are added before sorry, should have mentioned that

Comment: essentially i just need to get rid of this resource id thing? which is the pointer?

Comment: Then just delete the two lines I mentioned originally.... but whenever using code found on the web, it's a good idea to understand exactly what that code does and how it works

Comment: That brings me to my original problem unfortunately, `  $list = array (
      array('product_description', 'product_store', 'image'),
      array($data['product_description'][1]['name'], $data['product_store'][0], $data['image']),
  );

  $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 

  foreach ($list as $fields) {
      fputcsv($fp, $fields);
  } 

  fclose($fp);

  return $fp;` 

unfortunately this adds the resource id row

Comment: Then there has to be something else in your code that's outputting data, a var_dump() perhaps? Why do you have the `return $fp;`? What are you doing with that? Please don't tell me you're outputting that?

Comment: hmm not sure exactly. I ended up just writing my own function for csv formatting :

  `foreach ($list as $row) {

   $i = '0';

   foreach ($row as $field) {
    $i++;

    $output .= $field;

    if($i < sizeof($row)) $output .= ',';
   } 
   $output .= "\n";
  }` thanks for the help anyway

Comment: It's hard for me to know what's going on because its an extension for existing software - i didnt write it, this is what was calling it though / what it was being returned to>>`$this->response->setOutput` so yes :S

Comment: In that case, either prevent the framework from rendering output for this request; or actually return $output (not the filehandle) and have the framework send it to the browser

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, `rewind()` doesn't work with `php://output`, but it does with `php://memory`.

If your plan is to grab de output to make a force download later, then you don't need to rewind the stream; reading it with `stream_get_contents()` will be enough

You final code should be

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 

foreach ($list as $fields)
{
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
} 

$output = stream_get_contents($fp);

fclose($fp);
```